# Get width of text box in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, search, width

I have two text boxes `txtSearchDisplay` and `txtFind(one of 15 fields)`. `txtSearchDisplay` gets it's value from  `txtSearchText`. It's the text field the user will input for text searching across the whole form. I have my code adjusting to the top and left of the `txtFind` box, but I need it to also adjust the width of the `txtFind` box.

I've searched the web and haven't been able to find the right code for doing this. Thank you for your help. Max

```
Private Sub cboField_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

'Purpose:   Locate the display text box over the field to be searched,
'               and fire the search code.
'Note:      On forms where controls have different widths and heights,
'               you will need to set Width and Height as well.
Dim ctl As Control

If Not IsNull(Me.cboField) Then
    'Set ctl to the control named in the combo.
    Set ctl = Me(Me.cboField)
    'NEED TO GET THE WIDTH OF THE TEXTBOX THE CONTROL IS SHOWING ON TOP OF

    'Locate the search display on top of the control is simulates.
    With Me.txtSearchDisplay
        .Top = ctl.Top
        .Left = ctl.Left

    End With
End If

Call txtSearchText_AfterUpdate

Exit_Handler:
    Set ctl = Nothing
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

Code to get the active controls to show or hide

```
Private Function ShowHide(ctl As Control, bShow As Boolean)
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
'Purpose:   Show or hide the control, moving focus if it has focus.
Dim strActiveControl As String      'Name of active control on this form.
Dim strSafeControl As String        'Name of a control we can set focus to.

If ctl.Visible <> bShow Then
    'Get the active control name. Will error in Form_Load.
    strActiveControl = Me.ActiveControl.Name
    'Move focus if it's the one we are trying to hide.
    If (strActiveControl = ctl.Name) And Not bShow Then
        strSafeControl = Me.cboField.ItemData(0)
        Me(Nz(Me.cboField, strSafeControl)).SetFocus
    End If
    ctl.Visible = bShow
End If

Exit_Handler:
Exit Function

Err_Handler:
'In Form_Load, there's no active control yet, so ActiveControl.Name yields error 2474.
If Err.Number = 2474& Then
    Resume Next
Else
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".ShowHide")
    Resume Exit_Handler
End If
```

End Function

Code I'm trying to get working so far

```
 Private Function getWidth(ctl As Control)
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    ' Determine the correct size for the text box based on its text length
   ' Create a new SizeF object to return the size into

   Dim mySize As New System.Drawing.SizeF
 ' Create a new font based on the font of the textbox we want to resize
   ' Or, use this for a specific font and font size.
    'Get error on myFont. Doesn't seem to have system.drawing.font
    Dim myFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8)

   ' Get the size given the string and the font
   mySize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("This is a test", myFont)

   ' Resize the textbox to accommodate the entire string
   Me.TextBox1.Width = mySize.Width

   'This doesn't fire
   MsgBox ("Width " & mySize.Width)

   'Me.TextBox1.Width = CType(Math.Round(mySize.Width, 0), Integer)
End Function
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.width

Comment: I tried using ctl.SizeToFit on the control but the problem is I need to get the size/width of the text box (changes among 15 fields) beneath the control. @LynnCrumbling

Comment: Isn't `ctl.Width` in `cboField_AfterUpdate` the number you're looking for?

Comment: No because that would be the control width that I need to adjust. The control I need to get the width from is the ActiveControl

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Screen.PreviousControl property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.screen.previouscontrol):

```
ctl.Width = Screen.PreviousControl.Width
```

should give you what you want.

**Edit:**

The returned type (control) doesn't support width. You can retrieve width by casting to another control type first. So if your previous control would have been a textbox:

```
Dim prevTB as TextBox
Set prevTB = Screen.PreviousControl    
Me.OtherControl.Width = prevTB.Width  ' you can now access the width
```

If the previous control was a combobox:

```
Dim prevCombo As ComboBox
Set prevCombo = Screen.PreviousControl
Me.OtherControl.Width = prevTB.Width  ' you can now access the width
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not putting it in the right place, but this still isn't working for me. @Lynn Crumbling Can you point out where the code should go please?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the **required width** of a TextBox based on length of text, the hiden object Wizhook of Access has the right function : **TwipsFromFont**.

Look at http://pointltd.com/Downloads/Files/WizHook.pdf